# How come my output still displays new lines after my code confirms that I removed them all?

Tags: java, newline

I am trying to remove all new line or returns from my text however I am having a lot of trouble doing this. Even after I confirm that the new lines have been removed, they still appear visible in the output. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Here is the html text I am trying to parse:
**longDescription":"CUT FROM CANADA AA OR USDA SELECT GRADES OR HIGHER
13.21/kg"*

```
String flyerHTML = sbFlyer.toString();
System.out.println(flyerHTML.contains("\n"));
flyerHTML = flyerHTML.replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", " ");
System.out.println(flyerHTML.contains("\n"));
System.out.println();    

while (flyerHTML.contains("\"longDescription\":")) {
    String longDescription = "";


    // LONG DESCRIPTION
    flyerHTML = flyerHTML.substring(flyerHTML.indexOf("\"longDescription\":") + 18);

    if (flyerHTML.startsWith("null")) longDescription = "null";

    else longDescription = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(flyerHTML.substring(1, flyerHTML.indexOf(",") - 1));

    System.out.println("LONG DESCRIPTION = " + longDescription);

    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: You're unescaping HTML *after* replacing all linebreaks. Is it possible that they exist in the HTML as `&#10; / &#13;` or `&#x0A; / &#x0D;`?

Comment: &#xd;&#xa;  This is what separated HIGHER from 13 in the first output. I understand that &#xa; represents a $

Comment: Thank you Dragondraikk. Your comment really helped me. It was as simple as just replacing line breaks after unescaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add the replace inside the loop?

```
while (flyerHTML.contains("\"longDescription\":")) {
    String longDescription = "";    

    // LONG DESCRIPTION
    flyerHTML = flyerHTML.substring(flyerHTML.indexOf("\"longDescription\":") + 18);

    if (flyerHTML.startsWith("null")) longDescription = "null";

    else longDescription = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(flyerHTML.substring(1, flyerHTML.indexOf(",") - 1));
    longDescription = longDescription.replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", " ");
    System.out.println("LONG DESCRIPTION = " + longDescription);

    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You are right. The solution was to replaceAll AFTER unescaping.

Answer (score 0):

Your text may contain another line terminator characters. According to the [Pattern documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
A line terminator is a one- or two-character sequence that marks the end of a line of the input character sequence. The following are recognized as line terminators:

- A newline (line feed) character ('\n'),
- A carriage-return character followed immediately by a newline character ("\r\n"),
- A standalone carriage-return character ('\r'),
- A next-line character ('\u0085'),
- A line-separator character ('\u2028'),
- or A paragraph-separator character ('\u2029).